# URL regex mapping on GCP Load balancer

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

example.com/* (but not example.com/sample/[0-9]*/extraUrl) should hit backend-1

example.com/sample/[0-9]*/extraUrl should hit backend-2

I couldn't find a way to setup this up. Can this be done on GCP load balancer ?

Answer (score 0):

Configure:

- host = example.com
- path = /sample, /sample/*
- Backend = backend-2
- Default backend = host=any, path=any, backend=backend1

It should work. Let me know if it's not the case.

---

**EDIT 1**

With the edit of your question, I can answer that is impossible. Only prefix path is supported on Load Balancer.

Comment: Thanks @guillaume blaquiere. 
Edited the question a bit.